# Chrome extension published on chrome web store does not work in Chrome book

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I have developed an Chrome installable app as an extension in Google Chrome and published it on the Chrome Web store.

The app is developed using Html5, AngularJS and Ionic framework . It works well as an extension but does not work on Chrome OS.

Can you please let me know if i am missing something or do i need to do any extra coding for the chrome installable app(extension) to work on a Chrome OS.

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: It cant bcoz it does not give me any error or such .. i hosted the app in the chrome web store and i tried to install it in an chrome book

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome app and a Chrome extension are different things. Check out this [article](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions). A general explanation is that extensions are part of your Chrome browser, hence having fewer UI elements, while a Chrome app is a standalone app that can be independent from your browser (still runs on Chrome though). I don't think it being on a Chromebook makes a difference here.